# Using WebSharper to render SVGs server-side

Tags: f#, websharper

I'm trying to generate SVGs server-side, passing them in to a client using WebSharper's RPC mechanism. I'm basing this off the `websharper-web` template, using dotnet core.

For the sake of thoroughness, I render the template like so:

```ml
// Site.fs
    let Draw ctx =
        Templating.Main ctx EndPoint.Home "Home" [
            h1 [] [text "Say Hi to the server!"]
            div [] [client <@ Artery.Main() @>]
        ]
```

I've defined an RPC method that returns my SVG:

```
module Server =
    [<Rpc>]
    let FetchDrawing () =
        let center = {Svg.Point.X=50; Svg.Point.Y=50}
        let r = 25
        let circle = Svg.Shape.Circle(center=center, radius=r)
        async {
            return circle |> Svg.render
        }
    // Returns an SvgElement.circle with cx, cy, and r set
```

This is fine so far, but I cannot, for the life of me, figure out how load this properly in the client. The closest I've gotten is:

```
[<JavaScript>]
module Artery =
    let Main() =
        let circle = Server.FetchDrawing()
        div [] [
            SvgElements.svg [SvgAttributes.height "100"
                             SvgAttributes.width "100"] [
                Doc.Async circle
                ]
            ]
```

This:

1. Type checks and compiles
2. Runs
3. Throws runtime JavaScript errors

Specifically, I get `TypeError: x is not a function`. SourceMaps link the error deep into a WebSharper library called `Snap.fs`, and which sheds... comparatively little light.

Is this a bug in WebSharper? *Should* this be working? What's the correct way to include an `Async<Doc>` in a client-side doc like this? If possible, I'd *prefer* not to use jQuery -- I'd rather return JS that asynchronously loads in the SVG, rather than having jQuery plug it in later -- but I'm open to JQuery answers if that's the best practice here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick answer is no, this will not work as is, unfortunately, and sorry for not thinking more clearly when I gave you guidance earlier on the F# Slack channel. On one hand, it's a WebSharper compiler *limitation* not to give a warning that you can not pass `Doc` values from an RPC to the client. The WebSharper [documentation page for remoting](https://developers.websharper.com/docs/v4.x/fs/remoting) lists out the requirements on types that can participate on such exchange, and unfortunately `Doc` doesn't qualify.

On the other hand, there are proposals to make RPC calls more aligned around serialization, for instance [dotnet-websharper/core#930](https://github.com/dotnet-websharper/core/issues/930), paving the road to enabling more types to work in RPCs, or one could just wire in support for `Doc` values in RPCs directly to enable your scenario, simply because they *should* work. This is one of those few corner cases that need to be covered, indeed.

What you can do now to circumvent the problem is changing your RPC to return a custom SVG representation (some AST of shapes, for instance) that fits your needs, and use that to convert to a `Doc` on the client side.

Comment: Ahh, OK -- got it. I had read that list, and casually assumed that `Doc` qualified. Alas! For my purposes, passing _something else_ -- a Shapes AST, or even just a string representing a `Doc` rendered to HTML -- would work perfectly well; I'll explore that, thank you very much.